# Calling jquery ScrollTop from AngularJS controller not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I built a recursive tree template. Every layer has a height of 28px and after the user searched all elements and clicked a certain results I recursively calculate the number of pixels I have to put in scrollTop(n) to focus the clicked element. The click on the search results calls the following AngularJS controller function.

```
$scope.scrollTo = function (orgunit) {
    console.log(calcParentLayersRecursive(orgunit)); // e. g. 2080
    angular.element("#mainstructure").scrollTop(calcParentLayersRecursive(orgunit));
    $("#mainstructure").scrollTop(calcParentLayersRecursive(orgunit));
}
```

The calculation works fine but I can't use scrollTop() neither with angular.element nor with $(..). I also tried to scroll a fix number, doesn't work from AngularJS controller. If I execute the `$("#mainstructure").scrollTop(2080)` in the developer console, it works fine.

Why and how can I fix it the issue?

Comment: Show us the `calcParentLayersRecursive(orgunit)` function code.

Comment: This is not relevant, this method returns a number and works fine. But the scroll does not work!